# How to escape ( parenthesis in stata - invalid '(' error r(196)

Tags: path, stata, parentheses

I have to replicate a do file of a colleague who used a macro for his file names. The problem is that the pathname  contains a parenthesis, which causes problems:

```
*setting directory
cd "D:/Dropbox (Center for Child Well-being and Development)/2020/Playground"

*setup
sysuse auto
save "/Dropbox (Center for Child Well-being and Development)/example", replace


*problem
global path "/Dropbox (Center for Child Well-being and Development)"
local file "/example.dta"
global data "$path`file'""

disp "$data"
use $data
```

I get the following output

```
. disp "$data"
/Dropbox (Center for Child Well-being and Development)/example.dta

. use $data
invalid '(' 
r(198);
```

I know that calling the macro within quotations as `use "$data"` would do the job, but as it is not my do file I would like to try to avoid changing every occurrence where the macro is used.
I tried to escape the parenthesis with `\(` and add various numbers of quotations at any position I could imagine while constructing the global. Also I tried to add escaped quotations `\"` which did work neither.

Comment: You could try `global data ""$path\`file'""`

Comment: Thanks @Wouter I have tried this and get the error
`disp "$data"`
`_b not allowed when e(b) is not present`

Comment: Yes, then it should be `disp $data`. But the point is that `use $data` and other calls to $data should work.